# Struts 2 nesting iterators

Tags: jsp, struts2, iterator, nested, ognl

I can't believe how something this simple can seem so hard to do in Struts 2.

This is approximately what I would like to do as it would be done in Java.

```
for (Parent parent : parents){
  for (Child child: parent.getChildren()){
     System.out.println(child.getName());
  }
}
```

That should translate to something close to this in Stuts tags:

```
<s:iterator var="parent" value="parents">
  <s:iterator var="child" value="parent.children">
     <s:property value="child.name"/>
  <s:iterator>
<s:iterator>
```

I assume *parent.children* should be something like ${%(#parent.children)} but I have not found a right combination of ${%(# characters to use :-). I could also use a link to a page explaining when to use which one of these.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
<s:iterator var="parent" value="parents">
    <s:iterator var="child" value="#parent.children">
        <s:property value="#child.name"/>
    <s:iterator>
<s:iterator>
```

Comment: Can someone explain the meaning of the # sign?  I made the same mistake as the original poster.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

It works for me:

```
<s:iterator value="parents">
    <s:iterator value="children">
        <s:property value="name" />
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: More elegant than the accepted answer! This works because the current item in the ieration will get push on top of the stack, so there is no need to user var="xxxx" to access it.

Answer (score 1):

This is how the JSP code will look like:

```
    <s:form action="saveaction" >
        <s:iterator value="lstBean" id="lstBean" status="outerStat">
            <s:textfield value="%{name}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].name"/>
            <s:textfield value="%{amt}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].amt"/>
            <s:textfield value="%{id}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].id"/>
            <s:iterator value="%{lstString}" status="myStat">
                <s:textfield name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].lstString[%{#myStat.index}]"/>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator>
        <s:submit value="Click me to submit lstBean"/>
    </s:form>
```

Following is the bean(XBean) whose List is used in the JSP:

```
public class XBean
{    
private ArrayList<String> lstString=new ArrayList<String>();
private String name;
private Double amt;
private Integer id;
//Getters and setters of fields
}
```

Now you can simply have a field lstBean with setters in your submitting action (saveaction) and hey you are done.

Comment: So you mean in the inner iteration I can also get access to the outer iteration part value? Great.....

Answer (score 1):

For Struts 2.3.x you can use this example, extracted from http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/iterator-tag-examples.html

In this example, 'countries' is a list of country objects, each of which has a name and a list of cities. Each city has a name.

```
<s:iterator value="countries">
    <s:iterator value="cities">
        <s:property value="name"/>, <s:property value="[1].name"/><br>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

They refer to a specific position on the stack: '[1]'. The top of the stack, position 0, contains the current city, pushed on by the inner iterator; position 1 contains the current country, pushed there by the outer iterator.