# Comparing Struts 2 Nested Iterators

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Suppose that I have two objects with the same property name that I am iterating over with Struts 2.

```
class Book {

// assume that there is a public getter and setter
public String title;

public List<Chapter> chapterList;

}

class Chapter {

public String title;

}
```

In my JSP page, I want to iterate over the Book and Chapter. While iterating, how would I display a special message when the Book's title is the same as the Chapter's title?

```
<s:iterator value="bookList">
 <s:iterator value="chapterList">
  <s:if test="book.title.equals(chapter.title)">
   Same title
  </s:if>
 </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

How would I fix the s:if tag in the above snippet to compare the book title with the chapter title?

Thanks!

Note: This is very similar to the following stackoverflow question (but in that question they only print the property name without doing a comparison and the property name is differently on the parent and child objects):

[Struts 2 nesting iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327466/struts-2-nesting-iterators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [standard EL operators](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaik) `==` or `eq` to test the (String) values for equality:

```
<s:if test="%{book.title == chapter.title}">
```

or (a *bit* more XHTML friendly)

```
<s:if test="%{book.title eq chapter.title}">
```

Comment: Would that really work? I have an entire list of books and a list of chapters. I imagine that I would need something like bookList.title == bookList.chapterList.title (which would not work since it doesn't know which element of the list to examine).

Comment: Erm, in your (pseudo)code example you're already iterating over the both lists. Or is your problem also that you don't know how to iterate over them?