# Struts2 : trouble when updating textfields in iterators

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have some trouble when trying updating some data, I'm facing some exceptions...

I read that [Struts 2 nesting iterators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327466/struts-2-nesting-iterators) and applied modifications, but it does not work...

Here's Java classes :

```
 public class Epreuveevb implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idEpreuve;
    private String nom;
    private int coef;
    private int note;
    private int idExamen;

/* all setters and getters */
```

Then the second :

```
public class Examenevb implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idJury;
    private String nom;
    private String prenom;
    private List<Epreuveevb> listeEpreuves = null;

/* all setters and getters */
```

Finally, this is the highest class (with servlets) :

```
    public class Saisie extends ActionSupport {

        static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Saisie.class);

        private int idJury;
        private Jury leJury;
        private List<Examenevb> lesExamens;

[...]

        public List<Examenevb> getLesExamens() {
            return lesExamens;
        }
        public void setLesExamens(List<Examenevb> lesExamens) {
            this.lesExamens = lesExamens;
        }
```

And now JSP :

```
            <s:form theme="simple" action="relevernote">
        <table class="notation">
            <tbody>
                <s:iterator value="lesExamens" status="examstat">
                <tr>
                    <td class="default"><span class="gras">${nom}</span>, ${prenom}</td>
                    <s:iterator value="listeEpreuves" status="eprstat">
                    <td>
                        ${nom}<br/>
                        <s:textfield name="lesExamens[%{#examstat.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#eprstat.index}].note"/>
                        <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    </td>
                    </s:iterator>
                </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <p class="center"><s:submit value="Valider"/></p>
        </s:form>
```

All is fine, all marks are correctly in text fields. For eg, this is final HTML page:

```
        <td class="default"><span class="gras">EL MORABIT</span>, MOHAMED</td>

                <td>
                    Maths<br/>
                    <input type="text" name="lesExamens[0].listeEpreuves[0].note" value="0" id="relevernote_lesExamens_0__listeEpreuves_0__note"/>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </td>
```

But when submitting, I see in log :

```
    2017-05-16 17:29:44,910 ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor [notifyDeveloperParameterException] Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'lesExamens[0].listeEpreuves[0].note' on 'class evb.pg.notation.Saisie: Error setting expression 'lesExamens[0].listeEpreuves[0].note' with value ['0', ]
2017-05-16 17:29:44,914 ERROR com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor [notifyDeveloperParameterException] Developer Notification (set struts.devMode to false to disable this message):
Unexpected Exception caught setting 'lesExamens[0].listeEpreuves[1].note' on 'class evb.pg.notation.Saisie: Error setting expression 'lesExamens[0].listeEpreuves[1].note' with value ['0', ]
```

What's going wrong ? Any idea ?

I checked several times setters/getters, all is fine...

Comment: I changed Examenevb  class, I removed "private List<Epreuveevb> listeEpreuves = null;" and replaced it by "private List<Epreuveevb> listeEpreuves;".

Unfortunately, the bug remains...

Comment: Make sure you have correct getters and setters

Comment: Hello Roman, I just checked all setters & getters, all is fine.

However, I'm reading a book dealing with Struts2. I may have found a solution : using Preparable interface. Hope I will fix this...

Comment: `Preparable` is used by another interceptor. It has also  another meaning.

Comment: Please tell me : what are the rules of Preparable ?

I have almost fixed my problem, using both ModelDriven and Preparable. When stabilized, I will report it.

Comment: Model driven is another issue. It's too broad to tell you all about Struts.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the problem, all is now OK. But I would like being advised as better solutions may exist. Please let me know if so.

Let me show you which modifications I brought.

First, I forgot empty constructors for Epreuveevb and Examenevb classes.

Secondly, I added Preparable and ModelDriven interfaces to ActionSupport class :

```
public class Saisie extends ActionSupport implements Preparable,    
    ModelDriven<List<Examenevb>> {

        static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(Saisie.class);

        private int idJury;
        private Jury leJury;
        private List<Examenevb> lesExamens;
        private int idPassageGrade;
```

Those interfaces force me two additionnal methods :

```
@Override
    public List<Examenevb> getModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return lesExamens;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```

Finally, JSP became a few heavier :

```
    <s:form theme="simple" action="relevernote">
    <table class="notation">
        <tbody>
            <s:iterator value="lesExamens" status="idexam">
            <tr>
                <td class="default">
                    <span class="gras">${nom}</span>, ${prenom}
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].idJury"/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].idAdherent"/>"
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].nom"/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].prenom"/>

                </td>
                <s:iterator value="listeEpreuves" status="idepr">
                <td>
                    ${nom}<br/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#idepr.index}].idEpreuve"/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#idepr.index}].idExamen"/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#idepr.index}].coef"/>
                    <s:hidden name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#idepr.index}].nom"/>
                    <s:textfield name="lesExamens[%{#idexam.index}].listeEpreuves[%{#idepr.index}].note"/>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </td>
                </s:iterator>
            </tr>
            </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p class="center"><s:submit value="Valider"/></p>
    </s:form>
```

To ensure all attributes are set, I added several  tags... maybe there is a better way. If so, please let me know.