# How to get value outside iterator in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I need to print `catalogo.id` because I need to get `catalogo` object from its id. How can I get it, because I have an iterator? Now I print `action?idprodotto=XX&idcatalogo=`

**jsp**

```
<s:iterator value="catalogo">
    <s:iterator value="prodotti">
        <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">
            <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="descrizione" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="prezzo" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="nPezziVenduti" /></td>
            <td><a
                href='<s:url action="cancellaProdottoDaCatalogo.action" >
            <s:param name="idprodotto"><s:property value="id"/></s:param>
            <s:param name="idcatalogo"><s:property value="catalogo.id"/></s:param></s:url>'>rimuovi
                    dal catalogo</a></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

**UPDATE**
Now, I got id of `catalogo` but in the action, I have a `NullPointer` error, I think that with `[1].id` i pass only string and not object. How can solve this problem?

**NEW JSP**

```
<s:iterator value="catalogo">
    <s:iterator value="prodotti">
        <tr style="background-color: #99CCFF">
            <td><s:property value="id" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="descrizione" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="prezzo" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="nPezziVenduti" /></td>
            <td><a
                href='<s:url action="cancellaProdottoDaCatalogo.action" >
            <s:param name="idprodotto"><s:property value="id"/></s:param>
            <s:param name="idcatalogo"><s:property value="[1].id"/></s:param></s:url>'>rimuovi
                    dal catalogo</a></td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

**ACTION METHOD**

```
public String cancellaProdottoDaCatalogo(){
    System.out.println(catalogo.getDescrizione());
    Catalogo tmp = catalogoDAO.getCatalogo(catalogo.getId());
    for(Prodotto p:catalogo.getProdotti()){
        tmp.rimuoviProdotto(p);
    }
    catalogoDAO.aggiornaCatalogo(catalogo);
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can solve this via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327466/struts-2-nesting-iterators - use the `var` property to bind the iterator property

Comment: @ALee but in this way i can't pass object, but i will pass a "string". Right?

Comment: Print like in a `<td>`-tag? Use `<td><s:property value="catalogo.id"/></td>` anywhere you want to print that column.

Comment: @beendr It is not working, you solution is like i did :(

Comment: @ALee i updated my problem. please check if you can :)

Comment: There are only strings.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the updated question I think you should use the `var`-attribute, as @A Lee already answered in the comments.

You have a nested iteration and if you want to access the first iterator you have to use some sort of reference to find the values from the first iterator. And `var` gives you the reference to the current element in the outer loop and pushes the reference into the value stack as **c**.

Same with the inner loop **p** references the current element in the inner loop.

As a side note: the struts iterator pushes the elementes of the current element into the value stack, so that you can easily just use *id*, *descrizione* etc. See the third example in the struts docs [here](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html).

Example:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="catalogo" var="c">
   <s:iterator value="#c.prodotti" var="p">
   <s:url action="..." var="urlCancel">
      <s:param name="idprodotto" value="#p.id"/>
      <s:param name="idcatalogo" value="#c.id"/>
   </s:url>
   <td>Catalogo Id: <s:property varlue="#c.id"/></td>
   <td>Prodotti Id: <s:property varlue="#p.id"/></td>
   <!-- other columns -->
   <td><a href="<s:property value='urlCancel'/>Link</a></td>"
   </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

Note the *#* before the refernce name, it's required in this case to search the variable in the context.